# I am trying this but i get error in npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Dev\Sangeet-App> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Dev\Sangeet-App/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Dev\Sangeet-App\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-27T07_40_49_402Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Dev\Sangeet-App>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not in the app directory you should use:

```
cd "your app name"
```